# Возможно ли создать в табличной верстке HTML подобную таблицу?

Tags: html, вёрстка, табличная-верстка

было дано задание создать подобный сайт с помощью табличной вёрстки,
однако как не пытаюсь сделать подобное разделение верхнего ряда и последнего, никак не выходит, я начинаю сомневаться, что это вообще возможно
столбики просто отказываются становиться ровными или стираются вовсе
буду очень благодарен за помощь

[image: то, что мне нужно сделать]

```html
<html>
<title>ehh</title>
<head>
</head>
<body >
  <table border="1"> 
<tr>
    <td colspan ="2">
        fffff
    </td>
    
    <td colspan ="2">
        fffff
    </td>
    
    <td colspan ="2">
        fffff
    </td>
    
    <td colspan ="2">
        fffff
    </td>
    
    <td colspan ="2">
        fffff
    </td>
    
</tr>
<tr>
    <td rowspan = "2" colspan="10">
        fgfgfgfgfgfgfggfgfgfgfgfgfgf
    </td>

</tr>
<tr>
    
</tr>

<tr>
    <td colspan="5">
        fgfg
    </td>
    
    <td colspan="5">
        fgfg
    </td>
    
</tr>

</table> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Добавьте ваши попытки, чтобы было от чего отталкиваться.

Comment: @Павел, добавил

Comment: похоже нужно, чтобы была обычная ячейка, без спанов, чтобы правильно считалось

Answer (score 2):

Судя по всему, таблице нужно рассчитывать `span` на основе чего-то.

1. должна быть единичная ячейка
2. задать размеры колонок в `col`.

Например:

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<title>ehh</title>

<head>
</head>

<body>

  <table border="1" >
    <col width="10">
    <col width="10">
    <col width="10">
    <col width="10">
    <col width="10">
    <col width="10">
    <col width="10">
    <col width="10">
    <col width="10">
    <col width="10">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        fffff
      </td>

      <td colspan="2">
        fffff
      </td>

      <td colspan="2">
        fffff
      </td>

      <td colspan="2">
        fffff
      </td>

      <td colspan="2">
        fffff
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="10">
        fgfgfgfgfgfgfggfgfgfgfgfgfgf
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="5">
        fgfg
      </td>

      <td colspan="5">
        fgfg
      </td>

    </tr>

  </table>
</body>

</html>
```